# How to restrict the TYPE of INPUT in my JFormattedTextField in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Component frame;

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();

        //To set the position of the frame window in the center of the screen regardless of the screen resoluiton...
        Dimension d = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int left = (d.width - this.getWidth()) / 2;
        int top = (d.height - this.getHeight()) / 2;
        this.setLocation(left, top);
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jFormattedTextField2 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Enter Only Integers");

        jLabel2.setText("Enter Only Alphabets");

        jButton1.setText("Done!");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        // SETTING THE COMPONENTS...
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 144, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jFormattedTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 144, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(120, 120, 120)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addGap(14, 14, 14))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 31, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(29, 29, 29))
        );

        pack();
    }

    // NOW HERE GOES THE LOGIC...
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        try {
            //Must take only INTEGERS.
            String str1 = jFormattedTextField1.getText();
            int entered_integer = Integer.parseInt(str1);

            //Must take only ALPHABETS.
            String str2 = jFormattedTextField2.getText();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Entered Integer is: " + entered_integer + "\nEntered Aplhabet is: " + str2);
            jFormattedTextField1.setText("");
            jFormattedTextField2.setText("");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Oops!, You did something wrong!");
            jFormattedTextField1.setText("");
            jFormattedTextField2.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;

}
```

Can anyone tell me why this is used? :

```
jFormattedTextField.setFormatterFactory(
new DefaultFormatterFactory(new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat("#0"))));
```

Comment: -1, Did you not learn anything from your previous question? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679110/restrict-the-input-in-a-text-field-i-mean-that-if-any-field-is-suppose-to-take-in

Comment: @Amit Yadav: *"How to restrict the TYPE of INPUT in my JFormattedTextField in java swing?"*  Restrict it to what?  Numbers?  A specific form of text?  Fluffy kittens that don't bite?

Comment: @Andrew, +1 for restricting fluffy kittens. :)

Comment: @LBFF:  I *thought* this looked familiar!  Note that while it is very similar to the last question, at least the other one gave enough detail for me to suggest a `JSpinner`! ;)

Comment: @Andrew why restrict fluffy kittens???, @Amit You got to explain your question like what don't you understand, I'm sure if you google this you will get some results that will help you. If you did that, what confused you etc...

Comment: If any field is design to take INTEGERS as the input, so that field must not accept CHARACTERS(it must restrict to enter characters) and VICE-VERSA|

Comment: I googled and found InputVerifier. Will it help?

Comment: @Amit, yes now edit your question and tell SO what you don't understand about it.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this is used? :
jFormattedTextField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat("#0"))));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look a the [`InputVerifier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) example in [*Validating Input*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) and compare it to the `FormattedTextFieldDemo`.